# Connect to kurento web app from Android

Tags: android, spring-mvc, kurento

I have the SpringMvc web app integrated with kurento one2many web app. I want to connect to this from android app. How to do it if kurento Android SDK is not supported from over year ?
I need to user URL connection or something else ? Sorry for the stupid questions, I'm newbie in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding with the Kurento Android SDK (a.k.a. KANDS) That project was used to control the media server, not to connect to any of the tutorials. In the beginning, KANDS was supposed to be used to create pipelines in the media server, but it was a bit useless, as the moment you want to create a real-world app, you are going to set up a server somewhere and do all the signaling from there.

Long story short: you are the one that decides what type of signaling has to be done, nad KANDS not any other project (for now, but this will change soon) could help you with that

If you want to connect to one of the tutorials, you'll have to implement the signaling protocol of the tutorial, not that of the media server. Thus, if the tutorial expects a `startRecording` message, you'll have to send that JSON message to the server-side app, from your native Android App. Each tutorial has a different protocol, which you will need to implement in order to.

The tutorials are there just to show the capabilities. They are not full fledged apps, and shouldn't be used into production. The rationale is to show how Kurento works, and not how to create a SpringMVC app.

Comment: I am so grateful to you for the explanation!

Comment: No worries. I've also answered in the [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kurento/NKAkYL5HJuY/nPUNwJIeEAAJ).